# How to access other module method(outside VueJs) in component markup?

Tags: vue.js

I have one external module as following:

```
const externalModule = {
  thisMethodWantToUseInMarkup: () =>{
   alert("success");
  }
}
export default externalModule
```

i want to access `thisMethodWantToUseInMarkup` from component markup(from button A in following code).

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="bg-white">
   <button @click="externalModule.thisMethodWantToUseInMarkup()">Button A</button> <!-- is it possible like this directly -->
  </div>
</template>
```

what is the best practice to do this ?

Note: - I don't want to import global module in every component.

Comment: You are already exporting it. Just import it inside the component and use the method by import name.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple `import` in your `script` section of the view component (if you're using the default `.vue` files), or inside your javascript file. Something similar to:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="bg-white">
   <button @click="customMethod"> <!-- call your internal method -->
     Button A
   </button> <!-- is it possible like this directly -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { externalModule } from './externalModule'

   export default {
     name: 'mainComponent',
     methods: {
       customMethod() {
         externalModule.thisMethodWantToUseInMarkup()
       }
     }
   }
 </script>
```

Using internal method you won't bind user interaction with a specific implementation, and therefore switching the files/logic for it will simply mean changing the import file. This is useful for testing purposes in where you could dynamically load specific files based on environment for example.

Comment: I don't want to import global module in every component.

Comment: What this has to do with your question?  It's not Vue related. You can check how to set properties to objects and just create a service and attach it to Vue instance (or window if you are really desperate)